# Ember- Showing models data in view

Tags: javascript, view, ember.js, model

Im wondering here, how to show models data e.g Organization model>name field in ember view 
I tried something like this.

organization VIEW

```
OrganizationObserver : function(){
    var organizationModel = this.get('controller.organizations');
    //this.OrganizationComputedProperty(organizationModel);
    console.log(organizationModel);
}.observes('controller.organizations').on('init'),

OrganizationComputedProperty: function(){
  console.log("herrro");
}.property('organization'),
```

Model

```
var Organization = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    address: DS.belongsTo('agents/address')
});

// Initial data for Organization model, only applies when using
// FixtureAdapter
Organization.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   name: 'TU',
   address: 1,
 },
  {
   id: 2,
   name: 'TLU',
   address: 2,
 }
 ];
```

Main hbs

```
{{#each personFormCount}}
{{view 'organization'}}
{{/each}}
```

Controller

```
personFormCount: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
```

But i know that's wrong, because they watch for change behaviours which don't take place in model..

Cheers,

Kristjan

Comment: Please post the model definition and any other related code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i was capable of getting model to my view by `this.get('controller.organizations')`
Which is defined in route

```
controller.set('organizations', this.store.findAll('agents/organization'));
```

I looked at the select once again

```
{{view Ember.Select
contentBinding="organizations"
optionValuePath="content.id"
optionLabelPath="content.name"
selectionBinding="selectedAgent"
class="form-control"
}}
```

And i just added controller.organizations to contentBinding

```
{{view Ember.Select
contentBinding="controller.organizations"
optionValuePath="content.id"
optionLabelPath="content.name"
selectionBinding="view.selectedAgent"
class="form-control"
}}
```